# React.js frontend with Node.js backend not responding. Works with Postman

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-fullstack

I am developing a full-stack application and have been having issues getting the API and frontend to communicate I feel. I have written the API and it works as expected with Postman. However, when I am trying to access the same routes, it does not work as expected, I know this since I have console.log() statements in my routes that should log the output (i.e. it gets logged when I try with Postman), however, it is not getting logged.

Initially, I was not using cors(), however, I have added that but the issue persists.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

- part of Server.js

```
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/user", user);
app.use("/blogPost", blogPost);
```

- My PostMan request:
  [image].
- Same route trying to access on the frontend. My User.js file has the /users defined as such:

```
router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Inside users");
  User.find({})
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.send(error);
      console.log("error" + data);
    });
});
```

[image]

- In my backend package.json (i have two folders: frontend and backend with different package.json files), I have set the proxy as such. "proxy": "http://localhost:5050/" and both frontend and backend are running.

Comment: Please let me know if some more information is required to help answer this question. I am stuck and exhausted all the options that I could think of.

Comment: maybe body-parser will help you out!

Comment: does express.json() not offer the same functionality? I am already using that.